# Trouble with "destring" and keeping decimals

Tags: decimal, stata

I am new to Stata and i assume this is a beginner question. Yet I have just spent the last hour searching the internet for an answer to no avail!

I am using World Bank GDP data (imported from a `csv` file) and the data is in the string format.  When I `destring`, the GDP data that contains decimal places gets ignored and simply comes out as a big number.

```
 destring yr*, replace ignore("..")
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
yr2016
205276172134.901
..
13397100000
```

When I run the command I posted, it transforms to:

```
yr2016
2.053e+14

1.340e+10
```

As you can see the `.901` was tacked into the number instead of being perceived as a decimal space.

I have tried:

```
set dp period
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `format` of the converted variable:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate string = "205276172134.901"

destring string, generate(numeric)

list

   +------------------------------+
   |           string     numeric |
   |------------------------------|
1. | 205276172134.901   2.053e+11 |
   +------------------------------+

format numeric %18.0g

list

   +-------------------------------------+
   |           string            numeric |
   |-------------------------------------|
1. | 205276172134.901   205276172134.901 |
   +-------------------------------------+
```

Type `help format` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ignore()` option is removing every instance of a `.` in the string variable, Stata is ***not*** searching for a sequence of two consecutive `..`. There is no need to use the `ignore` option in this case. Try `destring var, replace force` and allow Stata to set rows with `..` to missing.

Comment: I think that @Pearly Spencer's answer has it.

Comment: The scientific notation in the original question would be 2.053e+11 if it was a formatting issue. The conversion to 2.053e+14 indicates Stata is ignoring all of the decimals.

Comment: It's not that you're wrong, because you are right. I'd suggest that you could have just added a comment to @Pearly's answer or at least cross-referred to it.

Comment: @Brie you have a point but ultimately ***it is*** a formatting issue. See my answer where i do just what you propose. The use of  the `force` option does not seem to make any difference.